# Filtering a list of objects

Tags: c#

I have a list of Object **Product** :

```
public Class Product 
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

I have a list of the above product :

```
List<Product> p ;
```

I am trying to filter this List , based on Search Criteria `ID, Title, Status.`

```
Example :
Id Title  Status
1  ABC   OPEN
2  CDE   CLOSED
3  FGH   RESOLVED
4  IJK   PROPOSED
5  LMN   SET
6  OPQ   CLOSED
7  MNO   OPEN
8  STU   CLOSED.
```

If Search Fields **ID 1** is entered : It should return

```
1  ABC   OPEN
```

If search Fields **Status OPEN** is entered : It should return

```
1  ABC   OPEN
7  MNO   OPEN
```

If Search Fields **Title "MNO"** and **Status "OPEN"** are entered it should return :
    **7  MNO   OPEN**

If **Id = ""** and **Title = ""** and **Status = "ALL"**  it should return all the elements.

I am going to bind this List of objects to an asp.net grid view.

So far the code I have is below :

```
var results = new List<Product>();

foreach (var prod in Product)
{
    if (prod.ID == txtProd)
    {
        results.Add(prod);
    }
    if (prod.Title.ToUpper() == txtTitle)
    {
        results.Add(prod);
    }
    if (prod.Status.ToUpper() == strStatus)
    {
        results.Add(prod);
    }
}
```

Can you please tell me how I can modify this code to achieve my results ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you want to use `AND` between your conditions, what you are currently doing is an OR, and you will add the same item twice when it satisfies more than one condition.

You could built a dynamic linq query based on parameters:

```
var query = Product.AsQueryable();
query = txtProd != string.Empty ?  query.Where(x => x.ID == txtProd) : query;
query = txtTitle != string.Empty ? query.Where(x => x.Title == txtTitle) : query;
query = strStatus != string.Empty ? query.Where(x => x.Status == strStatus) : query;

var results = query.ToList();
```

Comment: This won't compile because the ternary expressions are missing a `:` and an else condition

Comment: And also `ID` is integer you have to cast it either in `txtProd != string.Empty` or in `query.Where(x => x.ID == txtProd)`

Comment: Why would you want to run three `foreach` loops if all the conditions are given? Why not do it in one `Where` clause?

Comment: @PiyushParashar if this will be done in memory there won't be three foreach loops (see [why](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27180700/3010968)). but I was trying to make this in DB because this should be done in db. that's why I added AsQueryable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
results = p.Where(((product.ID < yourIDLowerBound) || (product.ID == yourID)) 
                  && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(product.yourTitle) || product.Title == yourTitle) 
                  && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(product.yourStatus) || product.Status == yourStatus)).ToList();
```

Comment: This doesn't account for any of the search criteria not being applied.

Answer (score 0):

As a single Linq query it would look like this:

```
var results = p.Where(x => 
     (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtProd) || x.ID == Convert.ToInt32(txtProd))
         && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtTitle) || x.Title == txtTitle) 
         && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strStatus) || x.Status == strStatus)).ToList();
```

By the way, in the question the List `results` is of type `Task` and you try to add `Products`, this is not possible.

Comment: That was a typo .. changed it . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
    var results = new List < Product > ();
    if (strStatus == "ALL" || txtProd == "" || txtTitle == "")
        results = p;
    else
        foreach(var prod in p) {
            if (prod.ID == Int32.Parse(txtProd)) {
                results.Add(prod);
            }
            if (prod.Title.ToUpper() == txtTitle) {
                results.Add(prod);
            }
            if (prod.Status.ToUpper() == strStatus) {
                results.Add(prod);
            }
        }
    results = results.Distinct()
        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a product query method. I think this meets all of requirements, I don't think any other covered the "ALL" requirement.

```
    public List<Product> ProductQuery(List<Product> Products
        , int? IDCriteria
        , string TitleCriteria
        , string StatusCriteria)
    {
        var query = Products.AsQueryable();

        if (IDCriteria != null)
        {
            query.Where(x => x.ID == IDCriteria);
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(TitleCriteria))
        {
            query.Where(x => x.Title == TitleCriteria);
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(StatusCriteria))
        {
            if (StatusCriteria.Equals("all", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                query.Where(x => x.Status.Length > 0 || String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Status)); //will return any status
            }
            else
            {
                query.Where(x => x.Status == StatusCriteria);
            }
        }

        return query.ToList();
    }
```